# pandas fillna with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I used `pandas.concat` to join several `Dataframe` together and would like to fill the `NaN` values in one column with the `value` of several other columns.

To get the below table, I did: `z = pandas.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0, join='outer')`

**concatenated table**

```
    C_header1    C_header2   C_header3   Column1    Column2    Column3
0   Item1        NaN         NaN         Values     Values     Values
1   Item2        NaN         NaN         Values     Values     Values
2   Item3        NaN         NaN         Values     Values     Values
3   Item4        NaN         NaN         Values     Values     Values
4   Item5        NaN         NaN         Values     Values     Values
5   NaN          Item6       NaN         Values     Values     Values
6   NaN          Item7       NaN         Values     Values     Values
7   NaN          Item8       NaN         Values     Values     Values
8   NaN          NaN         Item9       Values     Values     Values
9   NaN          NaN         Item10      Values     Values     Values
```

Currently, I am running the below code to put `C_header1, C_header2, C_header3` together

```
z['C_header1'].fillna(z['C_header2'], inplace=True)
z['C_header1'].fillna(z['C_header3'], inplace=True)
z.drop(['C_header2', 'C_header3'], inplace=True)
```

**To get**

```
    C_header1    Column1    Column2    Column3
0   Item1        Values     Values     Values
1   Item2        Values     Values     Values
2   Item3        Values     Values     Values
3   Item4        Values     Values     Values
4   Item5        Values     Values     Values
5   Item6        Values     Values     Values
6   Item7        Values     Values     Values
7   Item8        Values     Values     Values
8   Item9        Values     Values     Values
9   Item10       Values     Values     Values
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this? Feels like i'm missing something

Comment: It looks like you're getting the desired output, and you're using pandas native functions to accomplish the task. I'm not clear on what you're asking.

Comment: Yep, I am getting the desired output. But i can't seem to `fillna` with multiple `C_headers`. IE: `fillna([z['C_headers2'], z['C_headers3']], inplace=True)` is wrong. Is there a 1 liner code that I could run to achieve this?

Comment: You can chain the first part: `df['C_header1'].fillna(df['C_header2'].fillna(df['C_header3']))`

Answer (score -2):

If you make sure that your `df1`, `df2` and `df3` have the same columns, the concatenation is done as desired.

In this case, you could do:

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
df3.columns = df1.columns

# at this point concat will give you the desired result
pandas.concat(rename_columns(df1, df2, df3))
```

**NOTE** Generally speaking, you're better off using [pandas.DataFrame.rename](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename your columns.